# How to integrate C program with init file?

Tags: bash, command-line, kernel, init, init-script

So I am working on building minimal os using busybox. What I want is I want to run my .net program from BIOS. But I am not sure linux will run .net program or not, so to clear my path I am using C program instead of .net program. I am generating initrd.img file successfully. Now before generating initrd.img file. I want to integrate my **hello.c** program with init file.

This command I used to read file and which is reading C program code successfully. `echo 'cat /etc/hello.c' >> init`

Now I want to execute this **hello.c**. So I tried following command but it not working as `cat` command.

```
echo 'gcc -o echo /etc/hello.c' >> init
echo 'chmod +x echo' >> init
echo './echo' >> init
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
/init: line 6: gcc: not found
chmod: echo: No such file or directory
/init: line 8: ./echo: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is failing because you don’t have `gcc` in your initrd.

You should not ship `hello.c` in your initrd; you should build the program and ship *that* instead in your initrd. You should also specify the full path to your program when attempting to run it.