# How to execute wine command through busbox?

Tags: bash, shell-script, busybox, init-script

I am building minimal operating system using busybox.I am writing `init` file, I want to call `script1.sh` file from `init` file.

Challenges I am facing are:

1. After running `init` file it is showing `./script1.sh : not found`
2. In `script1.sh` it has `wine` command which calls `.exe`, I am not `wine` is supported by busybox. So how Can I run `.exe` through **busybox**

Please help me to solve above challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Same as [previously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/734544/86440), specify the full path to your script. If that still doesn’t work, [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734864/edit) to include the script’s contents (at least its first line).
2. Busybox doesn’t include Wine; if you need Wine, you’ll have to make it available separately. I take it you’re trying to run a .Net WPF program; there’s no way of doing that only using Busybox.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I include or make available `wine` for busybox.
I am using busybox because I am builiding minimal os.

Comment: You can’t. Wine is separate from Busybox.